# Did my file get damaged when blender crashed?

Tags: particles, error

I was working on file that has a particle system ( fluid with a lot of options in physics ) which made blender kind of slow. Then I undid a step and suddenly blender shut down .
I tried to open the file again but blender kept shutting down before opened it. I checked other files in blender and they worked fine, except for that one which blender shut down. I don`t know what happened. Does that mean that the file has been damaged? Knowing that the file`s size is just 12.8 mb
I use blender 2.78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen files getting corrupted this way yet, and I've had a couple of crashes in similar situations, trying to bake particles included. Blender is very good in informing you it can't open something, it usually spits an error saying it can't open a file for X reason. Since you're crashing I'm more inclined to think your computer isn't powerful enough to deal with this file.

I suggest you to:

1. Before anything make a copy of that file, just for good measure.
2. Look for a blend1 file in the same folder and see if this one opens.
3. If not rename the cache_fluid folder used for this simulation (or the sim files themselves) then try to open the original file.
4. If you fail you can create a new file and try to append the crashing one to see what happens. Append to whole scene, or just parts if the rest doesn't matter.
5. If it isn't under NDA you may ask someone with a more powerful build to try to open your file. They may split the file in smaller files for you, or disable the simulation so you computer can work on it again. If you don't know anyone directly you can upload it and share the link here.
6. Alternatively you can try the methods listed here (https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4x8o0w/method_to_recover_corrupted_blend_files/).

Answer (score 0):

Back form future! I think i found a solution!
My .blend file crashed suddenly, and i couldn't open it again no matter what! I tried appending the scene to another .blend file but it keeps crashing...! then i remembered the action i took right before blender crashing, and it was that i added a curve with very high res bevel! therefore, i tried to append all the objects from the old .blend except the object that caused the crash ( curve )! and it worked just fine! had to do some tweaks but generally it works!